# Can anyone give me an instance of 3SAT with exactly one solution?

Tags: satisfiability, 3-sat

I need an instance of 3SAT with exactly one solution but I cannot think of or find one anywhere. Can anyone please give me an example?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Try this:
$$
(A \lor B \lor C) 
\land
(A \lor B \lor \lnot C) 
\land
(A \lor \lnot B \lor C) 
\land
(A \lor \lnot B \lor \lnot C) 
\land
(\lnot A \lor B \lor C) 
\land
(\lnot A \lor B \lor \lnot C) 
\land
(\lnot A \lor \lnot B \lor C) 
$$

Comment: But this isn't NPC in the size of the input? You have 2^n - 1 clauses. Iterate them linearly and check who's missing.

Comment: The question asked for an instance of 3SAT with exactly one solution. My answer gives such an instance.

Answer (score 25):

The empty 3SAT instance (over no variables) has one solution.

Comment: Fitting username.

Answer (score 17):

If you are seeking a formula with 3 variables $x$, $y$, $z$, then you can consider clauses $(\ell_x \vee \ell_y \vee \ell_z)$ where $\ell_x$ is either $x$ or $\neg x$ (and same thing for $\ell_y$ and $\ell_z$). There is a total of 8 such clauses. If you consider a conjunction of all 8 clauses and remove exactly one of them, you get a 3-CNF formula with exactly one solution.

For exemple, if you remove the clause $(\neg x \vee y\vee z)$, then the solution to the formula is given by $x = \top$, $y = \bot$ and $z = \bot$.

Answer (score 11):

One variable: $(A \lor A \lor A)$

Answer (score 3):

Just about every puzzle game can be formulated as a 3SAT with a unique solution.  Sudoku is perhaps the canonical example.

Comment: You have to be careful, though, that the conversion from SAT to 3SAT maintains this property.

Answer (score 3):

Semiprime factoring.

Define an unsigned integer multiplication circuit such that X * Y = P.

Define P as a constant equal to an arbitrary semiprime number (there are an infinity of such numbers).

Define X and Y as free variables such that they have one less bit than P (to ban the solution 1 * P and P * 1).

Add the constraint that X <= Y (to ban the solution Y * X).

Convert the multiplication circuit to a 3SAT formula (clauses for each OR,AND,XOR gate, each gate of the circuit should have 3 variables, then the clauses ban the incorrect combinations). The bits of P are unit clauses.

The only way to satisfy this formula is to put X and Y in the right order as the input. Just like in the circuit, the rest of the formula is defined by the input. By the mathematical definition of a semiprime number, there no other way to obtain P through multiplication except by multiplying X and Y, or 1 and itself.

Depending on your goals, this is a convenient approach because you can generate an infinity of random formulas with unique solution.

*(However, the formula's unique solution should be exponentially hard to solve in the size of P, because multiplication is considered a one-way function.)*